# How can I include the last three (3) table.addCell from the output of my pdf?

Tags: java, eclipse, pdf, itext, java-ee-7

My code can't read the last 3 table.addCell .(table.addCell(card.getPk().getCardNumber());
table.addCell(card.getStatus());
table.addCell(card.getAmount().toString());) What is wrong in my code?

```
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(19);

        table.setWidthPercentage(100);

        PdfPCell column = new PdfPCell();

        column.setColspan(19);

        table.addCell(column);

        table.addCell(ReportConstants.REPORT_COLUMN_PURCHASE_DATE);
        table.addCell(ReportConstants.REPORT_COLUMN_PURCHASE_TIME);
        table.addCell(ReportConstants.REPORT_COLUMN_TRANSACTION_NUMBER);
        table.addCell(ReportConstants.REPORT_COLUMN_BUYERS_NAME);
        table.addCell(ReportConstants.REPORT_COLUMN_BUYERS_TYPE);
        table.addCell(ReportConstants.REPORT_COLUMN_CENTER);
        table.addCell(ReportConstants.REPORT_COLUMN_PAYMENT);
        table.addCell(ReportConstants.REPORT_COLUMN_IPG_REF);
        table.addCell(ReportConstants.REPORT_COLUMN_CREATED_BY);
        table.addCell(ReportConstants.REPORT_COLUMN_UPDATE_DT);
        table.addCell(ReportConstants.REPORT_COLUMN_UPDATE_BY);
        table.addCell(ReportConstants.REPORT_COLUMN_STATUS);
        table.addCell(ReportConstants.REPORT_COLUMN_CARD_TYPE);
        table.addCell(ReportConstants.REPORT_COLUMN_TTL_AMOUNT);
        table.addCell(ReportConstants.REPORT_COLUMN_OR_NUMBER);
        table.addCell(ReportConstants.REPORT_COLUMN_REMARKS);
        table.addCell(ReportConstants.REPORT_COLUMN_CARD_NUMBER);
        table.addCell(ReportConstants.REPORT_COLUMN_CARD_STATUS);
        table.addCell(ReportConstants.REPORT_COLUMN_AMOUNT);

    for(CardPurchaseReport cardPurchase : cardPurchases){

        table.addCell(dateFormat.format(cardPurchase.getPurchaseDate()));
        table.addCell(timeFormat.format(cardPurchase.getPurchaseDate()));
        table.addCell(cardPurchase.getPurchaseNumber());
        table.addCell(cardPurchase.getBuyerName());
        table.addCell(cardPurchase.getBuyerType());
        table.addCell(cardPurchase.getCenter());
        table.addCell(cardPurchase.getPaymentType());
        table.addCell(cardPurchase.getIpgRefNumber());
        table.addCell(cardPurchase.getCreatedBy());
        table.addCell(dateFormat.format(cardPurchase.getUpdatedDate()));
        table.addCell(cardPurchase.getUpdatedBy());
        table.addCell(cardPurchase.getStatus());
        table.addCell(cardPurchase.getCardType());
        table.addCell(cardPurchase.getTotalAmount().toString());
        table.addCell(cardPurchase.getOrNumber());
        table.addCell(cardPurchase.getRemarks());
        if(cardNums != null){
            for(CardMasterWS cardNum : cardNums){
                if(cardNum.getOrderTicket().equalsIgnoreCase(cardPurchase.getPurchaseNumber())){
                    CardMaster card = cardMasterDao.getCardDetails(cardNum.getCardNumber());
        table.addCell(card.getPk().getCardNumber());
        table.addCell(card.getStatus());
        table.addCell(card.getAmount().toString());
            }
        }
    }
}
    doc.add(table);
    doc.close();
```

Comment: What's the size of `cardNums` ? if it is zero (0) then it is normal that these three `addCell` methods do not run. Also check your condition `if(cardNum.getOrderTicket().equalsIgnoreCase(cardPurchase.getPurchaseNumber()))` if it returns `true`

Comment: Hi @elefasGR Thank you. the size of my cardNums is 30 and my if statement is true.

Comment: iText doesn't display incomplete rows. Does the funal row have 19 cells? If not, use `setCompleteRows` to complete the final row.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie the last row has 19 cells.

Comment: Have you made sure `cardNum.getOrderTicket().equalsIgnoreCase(cardPurchase.getPurchaseNumber())` ever becomes true? E.g. using log statements?

Comment: Hi @mkl. yes. I add logs and it loops the result 7 times.

Comment: So the card number, status, and amount should be added 7 times? And they don't show at all?

Comment: @mkl other table.addCell display to my output (pdf) but the last three table.addCell don't. Before the next row. I have 7 blank cells.

Comment: @mkl card number, status, and amount should not be added 7 times. I am still wondering why I get 7 blank cell every row.

Comment: To me that sounds like the contents of `cardNum` or `card` are wrong. Have you checked whether those cells may simply be empty because the data you put into them is empty?

Answer (score 0):

Hi @mkl I found out that some of records don't own a card. I remove my if(cardNum.getOrderTicket().equalsIgnoreCase(cardPurchase.getPurchaseNumber()))‌‌​​ I change my code like this:

```
        List<CardPurchaseDetail> cardsPurchased = cardPurchaseDetailDao.getPurchaseDetails(cardPurchase.getPurchaseNumber());
        if(cardsPurchased != null && cardsPurchased.size() > 0){
            int ctr = 0;
            for(CardPurchaseDetail cardPurchased : cardsPurchased){
                CardMaster card = cardMasterDao.getCardDetails(cardPurchased.getPk().getCardNumber());
                if(ctr > 0){
                    table.addCell(" ");
                    table.addCell(" ");
                    table.addCell(" ");
                    table.addCell(" ");
                    table.addCell(" ");
                    table.addCell(" ");
                    table.addCell(" ");
                    table.addCell(" ");
                    table.addCell(" ");
                    table.addCell(" ");
                    table.addCell(" ");
                    table.addCell(" ");
                    table.addCell(" ");
                    table.addCell(" ");
                    table.addCell(" ");
                    table.addCell(" ");
                }
                table.addCell(bodyFontStyle (card.getPk().getCardNumber()));    
                table.addCell(bodyFontStyle (card.getStatus()));
                table.addCell(bodyFontStyle (card.getAmount().toString()));
                ctr++;
            }
        } else {
            table.addCell(" ");
            table.addCell(" ");
            table.addCell(" ");
        }
```

And it works. :)